# Counting filenames matching a regex in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following script

```
setup=`ls ./test | egrep 'm-ha-.........js'`
regex="m-ha-(........)\.js"

if [[ "$setup" =~ $regex ]]
then
    checksum=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

I noticed that `if [[ "$setup" =~ $regex ]]` returns the first file that matches the regex in BATCH_REMATCH.

Is there a way to test how many files matches the regex? I want to return an error, if there are multiple files that matches the regex.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex, or `ls`, for this.

```
matches=(./test/m-ha-????????.js)
[[ ${#matches[*]} -gt 1 ]] && echo "More than one."
```

We expand the wildcard into an array and examine the number of elements in the array.

If you want to strip the prefix, `${match[0]#mh-a-}` returns the first element with the prefix removed. The `%` interpolation operator similarly strips a suffix, e.g. `${match[0]%.js}`.  You can't strip from both ends at the same time, but you can loop over the matches:

```
for match in "${matches[@]%.js}"; do
    echo "${match#./test/m-ha-}"
done
```

Notice that the array won't be empty if there are no matches unless you explicitly set the `nullglob` option.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for why parsing `ls` output should be avoided.

Comment: Just personal preference, but I would use `(( ${#matches[*]} > 1 ))` instead of `[[`...`]]` and `-gt`.